# Trying to get Average rating for user in the Post List Django Template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

**Intro:** Supposing I am making a app where users are rated based on the types of posts they write I have a users profile page. If you come on the users profile page you see all the posts they have written and you see their overall rating. My below code is achieving this with no errors.

The Review is not for the Post it is for the people writing the post. They get their reviews on other parameters. Example post my Miss America `Jane Doe` and Post by Miss Universe. `Meg Ryan` The author of the Post have got their ratings elsewhere. Which is not a part of this question

*Example:* Profile Page

```
Samir T's Profile
Rating: 8.0
See Samir T's posts below
```

**Problem:** When users come on the home page. Which doubles as a PostList page. A site visitor will see all posts from different users I want the visitor to see the post author's rating instead they see `N/A on 10`

*Example:* Home Page (Post List View)

```
Post 1 
Author Samir T Rating: 8.0 /10 #intead they see N/A on 10

Post 2
Author John Doe Rating: 7.5 /10 #intead they see N/A on 10
```

My working code for Review **Models.py** (shows users profile page)

```
class Review (models.Model):
    review_from = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='review_from')
    review_for = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='review_for')

   def average_rating(self):
    counter = 0
    total_ratings = 0
    for item in Review.objects.filter(review_for=self.review_for):
        counter += 1
        total_ratings += int(item.ratings)
        user_rating = total_ratings / counter
        return user_rating
```

Profile **views.py**

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
   context['review_list'] = Review.objects.filter(review_for__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))
   return context
```

**Template**

```
strong>{{post.user.first_name}} {{post.user.last_name}}</a></strong>
{% if review_list %}
   Rating: {% for review in review_list|slice:":1" %}
    {{ review.average_rating }} / 10 {% endfor %}
{% else %}
     N/A on 10
 {% endif %}
```

> Above is all working code to show the users Ratings (Review) in his/her profile page. Now below are my attempts to make it in the Home Page (Post List)

Below are my **post models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    message = models.TextField()

   def user_rating(self):
      counter = 0
      total_ratings = 0
      for item in Review.objects.filter(review_for=self.user.username):
        counter += 1
        total_ratings += int(item.ratings)
        user_rating = total_ratings / counter
        return user_rating
```

Below are my Post List views

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context['review_list'] = Review.objects.filter(review_for__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))
       return context
```

Below is the **template** for Post List

```
 strong>{{post.user.first_name}} {{post.user.last_name}}</a></strong>
{% if review_list %}
   Rating: {% for review in review_list|slice:":1" %}
    {{ review.average_rating }} / 10 {% endfor %}
{% else %}
     N/A on 10
 {% endif %}
```

Shows below error

```
Post 1 
Author Samir T Rating: N/A on 10

Post 2
Author John Doe Rating: N/A on 10
```

Comment: In both your ratings methods, the last two lines are indented too far; they need to be outside the loops.

Comment: But really you should consider doing this in the database, with aggregation queries.

Comment: I find it a bit "weird" that you write this at the `Review` level. It thus means that every `Review` has an "average review"? Typically this is more something you would do on the `User` level.

Comment: Furthermore the `Review` itself is rather weird, since here people only review *people*, not the *post*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I just simplified the question to explain. The members are reviewed on some other achievements. I want people who come to the site to know that the post is written by member with certain achievements. The Review is not for the post it is for the people writing the post. They get their reviews on other parameters

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am sorry I did not add his to the question I will now. The Review is not for the Post it is for the people writing the post. They get their reviews on other parameters. Example post my Miss America `Jane Doe` and Post by Miss Universe.  `Meg Ryan` The author of the post have got their ratings elsewhere which is not a part of this question

Comment: @DanielRoseman `In both your ratings methods, the last two lines are indented too far; they need to be outside the loops. ` Could you show me that in code

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for guiding me to aggregation queries